# Databricks: calling widget value in query

Tags: widget, databricks

I've created a **widget called yrmo** with the values such as 202001.

I need to call this value from a query but it doesn't recognize it, I think because the field I am applying it to is Int but I can only reference the widget with quotes around it.

If I don't use quotes then it thinks I'm using a field in the table.  If I use single quote then it interprets it as a literal.  I've tried getArugument but it says it doesn't recognize it (do I load something?)

The query is is scala.

val x = sqlContext.sql("select domain from TABLENAME where **partsn_mo=yrmo**)")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scala's string interpolation with an expression inside of `${}` that **may** include double quotes.

So you could do:

```
val x = spark.sql(s"select domain from TABLENAME where partsn_mo = ${dbutils.widgets.get("yrmo")}")
```

Comment: Please help df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM  $SourceTableName  where 1=2")                                        here  $SourceTableName  is Databricks  parmater

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
 val query = "select domain from TABLENAME where partsn_mo=" + dbutils.widgets.get("yrmo")
 val x = sqlContext.sql(query)
```